# Features Hook after successfull import

Tags: 7, features

I wrote a feature module that contains content types and test nodes. After importing those nodes, a certain cache has to be rebuild.

Both hooks I know (`hook_install()` and `hook_enable()`) are called before the import happens.
Is there any hook that is executed only once after the feature import is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how the nodes are imported really. You should be able to use [`hook_modules_enabled`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_modules_enabled/7) which is the last hook invoked when a module is installed and enabled. You might need to tweak your module weight to make sure it's invoked after the import of the nodes.

Comment: Thanks that worked - however the hook is called `modules_enabled`

Comment: @Ghrommey, thanks, I don't know how I managed to get the link right but the name wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As of [Features 7.x-2.x-*something*](http://drupal.org/node/1782492#comment-6677806), there are new hooks available which should help here. There are now pre/post enable/disable/revert/rebuild hooks, see for example [here](http://drupalcode.org/project/features.git/blob/8a3d404dd84307898b5a1b2a37eaa62058b59473:/features.api.php#l386).

In @jantimon’s scenario, implementing `hook_post_features_enable_feature($component)` would do the trick.